# How does the built-in Audio of the Thunderbolt Display compare to the MacBook Pro Retna?

Tags: audio, macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display, quality

I'm trying to understand which device has better audio capabilities.  I tried to do independent research, but the Apple site only has generic information for the [MacBook Pro](http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/13-and-15-inch/) and the [Thunderbolt Display](http://www.apple.com/displays/specs.html)

What are the detailed audio specs of each device and which one is better for Audio?

Comment: Neither are exactly known for producing high definition audio. If you value audio that much maybe you should invest in proper external speakers or headphones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the technical specifications, the thunderbolt display has 2.1 stereo speakers with a subwoofer and the system is rated at 49 W.

No one would consider the any MacBook Pro with the small internal speakers to be superior to the wall-powered solution that is part of the display.

You will want something like an [external DAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter) if you are concerned about audio quality or want to connect speakers that are better amplified and suited to a special situation other than casual listening. The Display Port monitor is better than many $150 speaker systems, but you can also get quite amazing external sound starting at that price point in the US.